# Beautiful Soup Selector returns an empty list

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So Im doing the automate the boring stuff course and Im trying to scrape the amazon prices for the automate the boring stuff book, but it is returning an empty string no matter what and as a result an index error occurs at `elems[0].text.strip()` and i don't know what to do.

```py
def getAmazonPrice(productUrl):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'} # to make the server think its a web browser and not a bot
    res = requests.get(productUrl, headers=headers)
    res.raise_for_status()


    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elems = soup.select('#mediaNoAccordion > div.a-row > div.a-column.a-span4.a-text-right.a-span-last')
    return elems[0].text.strip()


price = getAmazonPrice('https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd-ebook/dp/B07VSXS4NK/ref=sr_1_1?crid=30NW5VCV06ZMP&dchild=1&keywords=automate+the+boring+stuff+with+python&qid=1586810720&sprefix=automate+the+bo%2Caps%2C288&sr=8-1')
print('The price is ' + price)
```

Comment: Also the text contained in the downloaded html says "Sorry, we just need to make sure you're not a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is accepting cookies.", there's a hint for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the parser to `lxml` and use `headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}`

```
def getAmazonPrice(productUrl):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} # to make the server think its a web browser and not a bot
    res = requests.get(productUrl, headers=headers)
    res.raise_for_status()


    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    elems = soup.select_one('#mediaNoAccordion > div.a-row > div.a-column.a-span4.a-text-right.a-span-last')
    return elems.text.strip()


price = getAmazonPrice('https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd-ebook/dp/B07VSXS4NK/ref=sr_1_1?crid=30NW5VCV06ZMP&dchild=1&keywords=automate+the+boring+stuff+with+python&qid=1586810720&sprefix=automate+the+bo%2Caps%2C288&sr=8-1')
print('The price is ' + price)
```

**Snapshot**:

[image]

---

If you want to use select then

```
def getAmazonPrice(productUrl):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} # to make the server think its a web browser and not a bot
    res = requests.get(productUrl, headers=headers)
    res.raise_for_status()


    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    elems = soup.select('#mediaNoAccordion > div.a-row > div.a-column.a-span4.a-text-right.a-span-last')
    return elems[0].text.strip()


price = getAmazonPrice('https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd-ebook/dp/B07VSXS4NK/ref=sr_1_1?crid=30NW5VCV06ZMP&dchild=1&keywords=automate+the+boring+stuff+with+python&qid=1586810720&sprefix=automate+the+bo%2Caps%2C288&sr=8-1')
print('The price is ' + price)
```

---

Try with this.

```
def getAmazonPrice(productUrl):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'}  # to make the server think its a web browser and not a bot
    res = requests.get(productUrl, headers=headers)
    res.raise_for_status()


    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    elems = soup.select('#mediaNoAccordion > div.a-row > div.a-column.a-span4.a-text-right.a-span-last')
    return elems[0].text.strip()


price = getAmazonPrice('https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd-ebook/dp/B07VSXS4NK/ref=sr_1_1?crid=30NW5VCV06ZMP&dchild=1&keywords=automate+the+boring+stuff+with+python&qid=1586810720&sprefix=automate+the+bo%2Caps%2C288&sr=8-1')
print('The price is ' + price)
```

Comment: I get this error: bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a 
parser library? Then i tried to install the lxml module and imported it and now i get      return elems.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @MahdeenSky : You need to install it Using `pip install lxml`

Comment: i did, but then i receive a new error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @Buddy check my code: it is `select_one()`  Not `select()`

Comment: i copy pasted that exact code and it's not working i still get attribute error

Comment: @MahdeenSky: strange I am getting the value here.

Comment: Strange mate.I am getting value.As you can see I have posted snapshot

Comment: strange, the first solution with select_one works but the other two with select, doesnt work

Comment: what i realised that sometimes your select one code returns None and sometimes it returns the actual price wtf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211648/discussion-between-mahdeensky-and-kunduk).

Comment: @DeltaHaxor Have you got any ideas on this issue. I am also suffering from the same NoneType error.

Comment: @KunduK Does the code still work in your environment? I tried to run the same code, but got the following message from Amazon. Do you have any ideas to tackle it?
"Sorry, we just need to make sure you're not a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is accepting cookies."

Comment: @alienwang apparently it was related to the user agents problem, get a user agent, with alot of values, a large user agent dictionary is what fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your request will trigger a 503 error from Amazon. Perhaps due to Amazon's anti-scraping effort. So perhaps you should consider some other means.

```
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'} # to make the server think its a web browser and not a bot

productUrl = 'https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd-ebook/dp/B07VSXS4NK/ref=sr_1_1?crid=30NW5VCV06ZMP&dchild=1&keywords=automate+the+boring+stuff+with+python&qid=1586810720&sprefix=automate+the+bo%2Caps%2C288&sr=8-1'

res = requests.get(productUrl, headers=headers)

print (res)
```

output:

```
<Response [503]>
```

Comment: can you give me an example of a website i can scrape ? since im stuck at this point and i need something that works before i continue the course